# Does GmailApp.getInboxThreads() get "Archive" emails too?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-apps

I have a quick question though, if I use `var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();` in conjunction with `threads[i].moveToTrash();` will that delete "Archive" emails as well? or will it skip over them?

Comment: this is something you could trivially try yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
```

The above code ignores any Archived messages because Archived messages are not actually still in the Inbox.